# Xpath and CssSelector not extracting data using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to pull the total listings at the top of the main section (in this case it currently says 72 Listings). I have tried both `By.XPATH` and `By.CSS_SELECTOR` with no luck.... Any idea why this isn't working?

```
driver.get('https://swappa.com/mobile/buy/apple-iphone-8/att')
n = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.01).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".col-xs-9 pull-left"))).text
```

Comment: Try this value for your cssSelector ```".col-xs-9.pull-left small"```

Comment: That does not return anything for me... Thoughts?

Comment: change ```.text``` to ```.get_attribute('innerHTML')```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To print the *text* `72 Listings` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("section#section_billboard h2 small").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@id='section_billboard']//h2//small").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://swappa.com/mobile/buy/apple-iphone-8/att')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section#section_billboard h2 small"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://swappa.com/mobile/buy/apple-iphone-8/att')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@id='section_billboard']//h2//small"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  value
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)